# SQLCMD use LIKE '%@%'

Tags: variables, batch-file, escaping, notepad++, sqlcmd

I'm trying to run a query using SQLCMD.EXE and have trouble with the LIKE portion.

```
WHERE email LIKE '%%@%%'
```

I think it is an error with cmd prompt rather then SQLCMD.EXE since I get the error:

```
Syntax error "@%'"
```

I am running this via Notepad++ (NppExec) pointing to the bat file like so:

```
H:\scripts\SQL.bat "$(CURRENT_WORD)"
```

This causes the query to be wrapped in double quotes before being used by the SQLCMD.EXE call.  The SQLCMD.EXE call then runs in the bat file like so:

```
SQLCMD.EXE -U user -P %pass% -S %server% -Q %sql% -d %table%
```

It works perfect on any query I use aside from this `LIKE '%%@%%'` part.

**UPDATE**

I've done a few more tests and think I have narrowed it down to being a problem with the `%` and the `@`.

So queries like these work fine:

- `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'test'`
- `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'test%'`
- `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%%test'`

But these will cause errors:

- `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%test'`
- `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%test%'`

This is fine since I am ok with doubling the `%` in my queries, but I've tried `%%@%` and `%%@%%` and they throw errors. `Syntax error "@'""` or `Syntax error "@%'""`, respectively.

Also, the reason for the variables is that I included some logic so it can detect table names and run for different servers and databases.

Here is the bat file

```
set sql=%1
iff %@index[%sql%,sur_] GT -1 THEN
    SET SERVER=server1
    SET table=tablename
    SET pass=password
else
    SET SERVER=server2
    SET table=tablename
    SET pass=password
endiff
SQLCMD.EXE -U usr -P %pass% -S %server% -Q %sql% -d %table%
```

The reason for the weird syntax is due to the command being run through TCC/LE [(see here)](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm)

Comment: Can you strip the problem down to the most basic elements where the error occurs, eliminating other elements that don't affect the root problem? If, for example, I have *test.bat* that is `SQLCMD.EXE -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q %1` and I run it like `test.bat "select 'it worked' as result where 'ihave@symbol' like '%@%'"`, it works as expected. What is it about your batch file or method of execution that causes this to fail?

Comment: My guess is that the error comes into play at the `-Q %sql%` part of the call, but I also have `%@index[%sql%,sur_]`. This is here to help determine which server the query needs to be sent to (table names are commonly prefixed with `sur_` on one server)

Comment: Can you post the contents of your batch file?

Comment: Contents have been posted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your reasoning is for doubling up the `%`s, but it looks like your intent is to find values in the email column that contain `@`. If so, you can try rewriting the clause as such:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('@', email) > 0
```

If it's the `@` symbol that is tripping things up, use `CHAR(64)` instead.

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(64), email) > 0
```

Comment: It's going into a batch file so `%@%` would translate to a variable named `@` or something weird.  I'm not exactly sure what is happening there which is why I asked the question :)

Comment: @DavidStarkey I've updated my answer. If it's the `@` symbol that is tripping things up, use `CHAR(64)` in its place. Otherwise, does the first suggestion work?

Comment: This works, but my end goal is to be able to run SQL commands through my text editor by using a combination of SQLCMD.exe and batch commands.  I'd like my queries to be as close to normal SQL commands as possible.  Also, I'm unsure how this could be translated for more complex email things (i.e. `email LIKE '%test%@%.%'`)

Answer (score 0):

When run query with sqlcmd, i found that `%` symbol will be removed. Let's say your query is :

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'test%'
```

The sqlcmd will read your query as

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'test'
```

So sqlcmd will not filter your result. Please use `%%` for query

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'test%%'
```

and you will get result

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'test%'
```

I have tested this on SQLServer 2005 & 2008